# Show block for specific content type programmatically

Tags: hooks, blocks

How can I show a block on a specific content type programmatically? I want in my image the 'basic page' selected.

[image]

I used the xxx_block_info() function, should it set in here?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the node_module file it controls the node type visibility using the [hook_block_list_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7).

So basically it might looks something like this.
NOTE: This is a non tested version.

```
function hook_block_list_alter(&$blocks) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  // list of all block deltas u want to apply this 
  $block_delta = array('deltas');
  foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
     if (!empty($node) && $node->type == 'page' && in_array($key, $block_delta)) {
       unset($blocks[$key]);
       continue;
     }
  } 
}
```

Comment: There is anyway in hook_block_list_alter to get the content_types choosed in the block config page?

Answer (score -4):

You can do like this:

```
function xxx_block_info() {
    $blocks['xxx'] = array(
    'info' => t('Xxx'),
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP,
    'pages' => '<?php global $node; if ($node->type == 'yyy') return TRUE; else return FALSE; ?>'
  );
}
```

Verify that the PHP filter module is enabled if you want to use BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP!

Comment: PHP filter is a VERY BAD IDEA and should probably have a dependency on [Bad Judgement](https://drupal.org/project/bad_judgement)